# Append database record in HTML5 builder fatal error

Tags: rad, html5builder

I have some code in my application:

```
    $dmMain->tblOrgList->append();
```

This code written with auto-completion, so everything is correct.
But, when I trying to execute this code, I have error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function append() on a non-object in
>   C:\Users\ASAP\Documents\HTML5 Builder\Projects\VitoOrgList\index.php
>   on line 18

Can somebody advice, where I can find a trouble?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried var_dump($dmMain->tblOrgList) right before your function call to see what the non-object has? Maybe var_dump($dmMain).

Comment: Yes, $dmMain is NULL. What should I change? datamodule.inc included at the top of mys source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Really, I have no big PHP experience :-]

I just added before calling $dmMain methods in function body:

```
 global $dmMain;
```